# Need desktop environment for kiosk like profile that can only run certain programs

Tags: distribution-choice, kiosk

I have a need for an extremely locked down desktop environment that would have three profiles

1. School - Can only run Libreoffice and Firefox.  When I say ONLY I mean ONLY - can't change any setting at all, not even the desktop wallpaper.  The ability to not even see settings would be ideal as well. This would be kind of like a kiosk profile where the desktop has shortcuts to run the two programs and that's it.
2. Games - Similar to School profile in that no settings can be changed but I could somehow put apps on the desktop a needed (i.e. - Minecraft)
3. Administrator/root - Can do anything, normal desktop experience

I looked around at kiosk desktop experiences but they seem to just limit a user to only one application, not the ability to switch between two or more.  Additionally I looked at kids distro's but they are seemingly just a streamlined desktop experience (no menus - which I like), but you still have the ability to edit user settings and whatnot.

Is there even a distro like this or something that could be customized to do this without a ton of work?  I know what I'm asking for is not normal

Comment: What you are looking for is not a distro, but a desktop environment.

Comment: Ok, updated the subject.  Thank you!

Comment: Note: You can launch a different desktop environment based on who logs in. Therefore you can have 3 different ones. This will make it much easier. You will also have to configure the Display manager (login program), to restrict which environment each user can use.

Comment: Ok, that sounds do-able.  Do you know what desktop environment would give me the desired outcome I mention above for #1 and #2?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can launch a different desktop environment based on who logs in. Therefore you can have 3 different ones. This will make it much easier. You will also have to configure the Display manager (login program), to restrict which environment each user can use.

- For ③ I would use KDE plasma (as most powerful, for power user).
- For ② I would use Gnome with a customised launcher (edited, to remove almost everything).
- For ① I would probably write a selector in TCL, that just selects from the two choices. With just a window manager (most desktop environments (KDE, gnome, etc) come with a window manager). Or same as option ②, but more trimmed down.

To lock it down (if display manager can't do it): have all users use the same environment from the display manager point of view. Then have this program check the user-id, and launch the real environment.

Comment: So this sounds like it will work good.  Only problem I foresee is that typically the display manager lets you change the desktop environment.  Do you know a way to lock the desktop environment to a user? Or at least a display manager that does not allow you to change the desktop environment?